# Hibernate Projection with aggregate function

Tags: hibernate, projection

I am trying to run a query which is built using Hibernate Criteria api

```
 List results = session.createCriteria(Person.class)
.setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
    .add( Projections.rowCount())
    .add( Projections.property("name"))
    .add( Projections.property("age"))
).list();
```

But when i am running this query i am getting an error

```
 "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function"
```

What is the reason behind this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your projection gets translated into a query like:
`SELECT count(*), name, age FROM person;`

The problem is that `count(*)` returns a single row while name and age yield a row from every row in the database table. You would need a more complicated query to select `count(*)` and then join that to your results from `SELECT name, age FROM person`

Alternatively you can just select your count in a separate query.